# Could someone help me with the server log interpretation?

Tags: logging, server, splunk

I know how standard server log looks like. However, sometimes I get logs that make me a little confused (I'm analyzing statistic data).

For example:

www-phalcon2 66.249.78.168 - [20/Feb/2015:23:59:59 +0100] 200 3251 4.69 0.001 192.168.64.125 3557 "GET /style/products.css?1414645533 HTTP/1.1" "-" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

The first IP belongs to the client. But what about the other ones? What "www.phalcon2" stands for (in general)? And also, what are the two values after the number of transferred bytes?

I'm sure that it's easy to interpret such logs, but I've done my research on the Internet and didn't find the answer. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Web server log output is highly configurable, so for the interpretation of a non-standard log format you should ideally have the log format definition available as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a W3C compatible log and is fairly standard.  The interesting thing about W3C formats is that they have a header where each line is preceded by a #.  The top of the file will look something like this:

```
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 12-Jan-1996 00:00:00
#Fields: time cs-method cs-uri
```

If you can search splunk for lines starting with a # (you may have to search over all time) with the same source type as your example then you might find the definition.  Without that definition, you cannot really parse that log.

An alternative is to assume it's an Apache custom log format (which doesn't generally have the header).  In this case you need to ask for the LogFormat or CustomLog configuration - this will provide you with a string called the format string - basically, a series of %elements that together represent the format.  You can find [a list of all the format specifiers here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).

I'm going to guess that the decimal numbers are the time taken to generate the request in both seconds (%T - rounded) and microseconds (%D - more precision).  However, this is a guess based on what is generally available in logging libraries - without the configuration or header information, you can't really say.